# Ubuntu One and hidden folders

Tags: sync, directory

I'd like to sync a hidden folder (the .gramps folder for the Gramps genealogy program) with Ubuntu One.

The idea is that I could take my laptop to the library, make changes to my database and then sync to have the same thing on my desktop machine (and vice versa)

When I try to add the folder, it isn't shown in the Ubuntu One GUI. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Ubuntu One control panel --> Add a folder from this computer and right click on the file browser window and select Show Hidden Files.
[image]